# Eclipse Juno maven-archetype-webapp handle oddly jquery plugin creating error in Project Explorer Directory

Tags: jquery, eclipse-juno, maven-archetype

I'm working under Eclipse Juno on a maven-archetype-webapp project done with m2eclipse.
I'm using Spring 3 and JSF 2.

I'd like to use some javascript with jquery. I don't know where to put javascript script and jquery plugin.

I created a javascript directory under webapp but Eclipse juno handle it oddly. I put Jquery . An error occur in Eclipse Project Explorer Directory.why ?

Where is the correct way to integrate javascript jquery in java web app under Juno maven-archetype-webapp project ?? Where do you put the files, or ask eclise to handle correctly?

Thanks a lot !

```
> src/
>     main/
>         java/
>             com/
>                 example/
>                     web/
>                         HomeController.java
>         resources/
>              Spring
>         webapp/
              javascript/jquery.min.js
>             img/
>             css/
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is Spring MVC, then usually what I do is setup a static resource to a javascript folder and include that in the war.  You can do this in your spring xml like thus:

```
<!--  Mapping Static Resources -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" />
```

This will map 3 static resources: a css folder, a js folder, and an images folder.  The paths need to be added under your web content folder, where you put your WEB-INF and such.  [This is a link to the reference documentation discussing this.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)

Comment: Ok i'll try but i'm not sure it will handle the problem eclipse meet.I post a picture of what i see in eclipse if i add jquery in webapp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988162/eclipse-juno-m2ecliipse-directory-structure-explanation

Comment: My proxy server blocks images from StackOverflow (it uses imgur, which we block), so I can't see the errors.  Perhaps you can copy/paste the text into the problem I might be able to tell you what it is.

Comment: It will be hard to explain but maybe you can answer this question. I don't understand if i have to put xml files under src/main/ressources or in webapp/WEB-INF. What do you put in src/main/ressources? How does it impact on the build? thanks

Comment: Is the problem your application XML files for Spring, or servicing your .js files statically?  I'd have to look back to one of my old projects, but I believe I usually put things under META-INF/resources and use the following as my mvc:resources mapping:  location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/**", which would essentially look in the classpath for /META-INF/resource/<anything>.  You can really put the resources anywhere you like, as long as you can get to them via a path.  If you use classpath:, the path will be relative to the root of your WAR/JAR